# Subsetting data from a csv file based on contents in another csv file in R

Tags: r, subset

Would want to get the information from a csv file - mf.csv based on a list of data(which has one column named PAN) stored in df.csv

```
dataA <- read.csv("C://Users//mf.csv")

dataD <- read.csv("C://Users//df.csv")

dataG <- subset(dataA, PAN %in% dataD)

write.csv(dataG,"C://Users//result.csv")
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think your `subset` code should be `subset(dataA, PAN %in% dataD$columnname)` as `dataD` is a `data.frame`.  Can you provide a small reproducible example and expected output (if the above doesn't work).

Comment: Hey thanx..it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the OP's code, instead of the column, the whole data.frame was used on the rhs of `%in%`.  The code should be

```
subset(dataA, PAN %in% dataD$columnname)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of these csv files, for example if they are too big to load into R or loading in R is slow, you can do this on the command line with `awk` and it will be much quicker.

```
awk -F',' 'NR==FNR {arr[$1]++; next} (($1 in arr) && ($2 in arr)) {print $0}' file1 file2
```

this will simply print the results but you can write it to your new csv:

```
 awk -F',' 'NR==FNR {arr[$1]++; next} (($1 in arr) && ($2 in arr)) {print $0}' file1 file2 > new.csv
```

[awk; searching file2 by file1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19611453/awk-searching-file2-by-file1) for reference.